# Rails 4: Error installing elasticsearch & searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

Setting up a search field on my web app. Using a gem called searchkick  for this
I need to install elasticsearch and java.

Installed java successfully and validated this on the Java website (using firefox)
-->You have the recommended Java installed (Version 7 Update 67).

installed elasticsearch using the brew command

see code below

```
Neils-MacBook-Pro:yelpdemo neilpatel$ brew info elasticsearch
elasticsearch: stable 0.90.7, HEAD
http://www.elasticsearch.org
/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.90.7 (31 files, 19M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/elasticsearch.rb
==> Caveats
Data:    /usr/local/var/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_neilpatel/
Logs:    /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_neilpatel.log
Plugins: /usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/plugins/

To have launchd start elasticsearch at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load elasticsearch now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    elasticsearch -f -D es.config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

When I try to launch elasticsearch using this command

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist
```

it gives me error

```
launchctl: Couldn't stat("/Users/neilpatel/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist"): No such file or directory
nothing found to load
```

when I try

```
elasticsearch -f -D es.config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

I get no java is detected

Answer (score 1):

After brew install `elasticsearch` try

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

info obtained from: [mubix/WhiteChapel](https://github.com/mubix/WhiteChapel/issues/4)

Comment: Its worth noting that the launch command still needs to be executed after executing this command.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew uses '/usr/local/' instead of '/Users/neilpatel/' so that you don't have to use 'sudo' when you 'brew install'... https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation

Just replace /Users/neilpatel/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist by /usr/local/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist.

Stephane's answer shows you where the plist file is on your computer.